# Problem installing uvc_cam on ARM/Hydro

Tags: robotic-arm, ros-hydro, build, uvc-cam, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Trying to do a uvc_cam install on a Panda Board under hydro following the Ros By Example instructions.  I get 55 successes and one failure.  the Package path is correct and roscd finds the correct source directory in ros_workspace.  I did call rosdep update and tried again with the same failure message.

I am guessing I am missing a dependency, but not sure which.

Here is the build log:

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [all] Error 1
team751@team75-pb:~/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140502-151735/uvc_cam$ more build_ou      tput.log
mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros/core/rosbuild/
rostoolchain.cmake  ..
[rosbuild] Building package uvc_cam
Failed to invoke /opt/ros/hydro/bin/rospack deps-manifests uvc_cam
[rospack] Error: package/stack 'uvc_cam' depends on non-existent package 'driver_base'
and rosdep claims that it is not a system dependency. Check the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or t
ry calling 'rosdep update'

CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):

Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'uvc_cam'.  Look
above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the broken
dependency!

Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:203 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [all] Error 1

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/159921/problem-installing-uvc_cam-on-arm/hydro/) by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 147 on 2014-05-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2014-05-02**:
Worked for me when I used catkin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

some packages not install.
[rospack] Error: package/stack 'uvc_cam' depends on non-existent package **'driver_base'** and rosdep claims that it is not a system dependency.

apt-cache search ros-hydro-driver-base, find the package and install it.

some packages else also not install, do the same thing

---

Originally posted by [nick](https://answers.ros.org/users/20305/nick/) with karma: 16 on 2014-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0